# ERROR: syntax error at or near "$" Position: 40 [Failed SQL: (0) SET SEARCH_PATH TO <SchemaName>, $user, public]

Tags: amazon-redshift, liquibase

We are using liquibase to deploy the data warehouses. We are facing the issue with the default schema name property of liquibase. When we set the value for the same to the schema in which we want the deployment to be done, it gives the following error -

> Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error
> at or near "$"   Position: 40 [Failed SQL: (0) SET SEARCH_PATH TO
> , $user, public]

The $user, should be in quotes and hence the issue is occurring. Is anyone also facing a similar issue with Redshift while deploying databases using liquibase?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_search_path.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is related to Liquibase version 4.11.0, just use Liquibase v4.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using --defaultSchemaName parameter, use **--liquibase-schema-name** parameter to set the schema for liquibase tables.

Comment: That property is already set and we don't have any issues with that property. This is the schema in which we want the changesets to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

workaround

execute in database something similar
ALTER USER user_name SET search_path to 'public'